# "fatal error: ddraw.h: No such file or directory" error in CodeBlocks w/ DirectX SDK

Tags: c++, codeblocks, directx-9

I'm using CodeBlocks to edit the source code for the 1999 game Carnivores 2. I have the compiler set up to support Direct X SDK (June 2010). I am ready to compile the code but I get the error in the attached image. Does anyone know what is wrong? Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q28kL.png

I've tried searching things up online but I couldn't find any helpful threads for CodeBlocks users.

I expect ddraw.h to no longer be missing and for the code to then compile correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you're using an (outdated) MinGW version that comes with CodeBlocks. Try downloading the last MinGW-w64 instead. It comes with `ddraw.h`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'll download the latest version.

Comment: https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download Which build do you recommend?

Comment: The 'regular' installer is named `MingW-W64-builds`.

Comment: Alright thanks that's the one I chose. Do I have to install the GLEW libary to have ddraw.h?

Comment: No, they're not related. `ddraw.h` comes with MinGW-w64.